# R: geom_point() using a function to choose shape?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to pick one of three shapes for a `geom_point` call, like so:

```
function shapen(pt) {
    if (pt$x < 10) {
        return(1);
    } else if (pt$y > 10 & pt$y < 22) {
        return(2);
    } else {
        return(3);
    }
}

p <- p + geom_point(data=rows, aes(x+bh$x,y+bh$y), shape=shapen)
```

But that's not quite working-- how I can check the value of 'x' on the rows of data to determine one of three or four shapes?

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `shape` in your `aes`thetics mappings. Manual mapping can then be tailored using `scale_shape_manual`:

```
library(ggplot2)
str(mtcars[,c("wt", "mpg", "gear")])
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(gear))) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("4"=1, "3"=2, "5"=4))
```

You can also precompute your shapes:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(myshape = case_when(
    gear >= 5 ~ 1, 
    between(gear, 2, 4) ~ 2, 
    TRUE ~ 3
  )) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = myshape)) + 
  scale_shape_identity()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to work well on a vector and return a vector of shape numbers:

```r
shape_generator <- function(x) {
    xtr <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
        if (x[i] >= 5) {
            xtr[i] = 1
        } else if (x[i] > 2 & x[i]  <= 4) {
            xtr[i] = 2
        } else {
            xtr[i] = 3
        }
    }
    return(xtr)
}
```

Then apply it to shape `aes` of geom_point:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape = shape_generator(wt))) + 
    theme_gray() +
    scale_shape_identity()
```

[image]